# Pass html as an input to an angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to create an `app-my-component` component, which can be used in the following way:

```
<app-my-component>
    <div>Some element inside</div>
</app-my-component>
```

Then I would like to use that component/html element inside the `app-my-component`, like this:

```
<p>You provided this element as parameter:</p>

<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="inputElement"></ng-template>
```

How is it possible? I was not able to find any documentation about this, but I once saw a code using this feature, so I hope it is still possible.

---

I added this to the `MyComponent` class:

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef)
public inputElement: TemplateRef;
```

But the element does not appear.

Comment: What does your template look like? Should be an <ng-content> in there..

Comment: DId you tried using content projection?

Comment: @Bozhinovski I've never heard of content projection. I will check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In parent component, wrap all the projected element inside ng-template like this

```
<app-my-component>
    <ng-template>
      <div>Some element inside</div>
    </ng-template>
</app-my-component>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ybarac)